# Unable to explicitly add a one to one foreign key during code first using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

Ok so I have two tables, `Student` and `Address`. I want one to one mapping between them.

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set;}
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public Address StudentAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string AddressName { get; set; }
        
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
        public Student Student;
    }
```

Earlier I kept simple, I didn't use `ForeignKey` attribute, I put `Address` object in `Student` class and Entity Framework did its work. It added a column named `AddressId` in `Student` table.

The things is, I want `StudentId` to go into `Address` table as a foreign key instead of vice versa. Currently Entity Framework is generating a foreign key in `Student` table where it is storing `AddressId`. I don't want this.

I want to know how to explicitly defined which table to contain the foreign key in Entity Framework when mapping one to one relation in code first approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try change your classes to:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set;}
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public virtual Address StudentAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressName { get; set; }       
    public virtual Student Student;
}
```

this because the key into one to one relationship is the same

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set;}
        public string StudentName { get; set; }      
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("StudentId ")]
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }
    public class Address
    {
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string AddressName { get; set; }      
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```